# how to bind with angularjs on page load

Tags: angularjs, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on a single page app using angularjs. The app has many navigator pages that run ajax calls.

The problem is that whenever the app launches all ajax code is run for all pages (although pages have not been navigated to yet)

I need a way to run the below only when the navigator page is requested. How can I do that without placing my code in a function and calling the function?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("welcome.htm")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    });
});
```

Comment: That sounds very odd and peculiar. Some where in the code you must invoke all those http requests yourself.

Comment: If all your controllers are set up like the one you've shown, then it makes sense.  You've got the `http` call in the constructor so it runs when the controller is wired up.  If you're using routing, you should use the route change event to load the relevant Ajax for that route.